# A simple zeroes polynomial which constructs another one

Tags: polynomials, roots, symmetric-functions

Let $P(X) = (X-x_1)\ldots(X-x_N)$ be a complex polynomial with simple roots.

I define 
$$Q(X) = P(X-a)-bP(X),$$ 
with $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and $b\neq 1$ so that $Q(X)$ is also a polynomial of degree $N$.

Let me note $y_1,\ldots,y_N$ the roots of $Q(X)$. I would like to prove that

- $Q$ has simple roots : $\forall i,j, \quad y_i \neq y_j$
- one cannot shifts from a root to another by the use of $a$ : $\forall i,j,\quad y_i \neq y_j \pm a $

I am not sure this is the case for all $a$ and $b$, but in the context of my problem it seems $Q$ has to verify these conditions.

I thought it would be a simple exercise, but I keep struggling on it.

Any help is much appreciated ! :)

Comment: The system for double roots $0=Q(X)=P(X-a)-bP(X)$ and $0=Q'(X)=P'(X-a)-bP'(X)$ in general will have curves of solutions in $(a,b,X)$ space. What makes you think you can avoid that? Or are additional restrictions on $a,b$ allowed, such as being close to zero?

Comment: You may take the $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a = i$, if it helps. But maybe I should have asked that I am interested in constraints on $a$ and $b$ for the propositions to hold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true.

As a counterexample, letting

- $P(x)=(x+2)(x-2)$$\\[4pt]$

  $a=5$$\\[4pt]$

  $b=-4$

we get

$\;\;\;Q(x)=5(x+1)^2$.

Staying with the case $n=2$, let $P(x)=(x-r)(x-s)$ with $r\ne s$.

Then for $b\ne 1$, the polynomial
$$Q(x)=P(x-a)-bP(x)$$
has simple roots if and only if either$\;b=0\;$or
$$a^2\ne -\frac{(b-1)^2(r-s)^2}{4b}$$

Let's try an example with $n=3$ . . .

Let $P(x)=(x-1)x(x+1)$.

Then for $b\ne 1$, the polynomial
$$Q(x)=P(x-a)-bP(x)$$
has simple roots if and only if
$$
4b^4+(36a^2-16)b^3+(-27a^6+108a^4-72a^2+24)b^2+(36a^2-16)b+4
$$
is nonzero.

The results of that example suggest that for the general case, trying to find  usable necessary and sufficient conditions on $a,b$ for $Q(x)$ to have simple roots is not likely to succeed.

As a more reasonable goal, one might try to find sufficient conditions for $Q(x)$ to have simple roots, expressed in terms of inequalities relating $|a|,|b|$.

For example, if $a$ is fixed, then $Q(x)$ will have simple roots if

- $b\;$is sufficiently close to $0$.

  **or**

  $|b|\;$is sufficiently large.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. But As I said I do not expect it to be true for all $a$ and $b$. Rather I would be glad to find restrictions on $a$ and $b$ for the propositions to hold, if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed edit @quasi, I guess it is a much safer program. 
For the second proposition to hold we find an equivalent constraint on $a$ and $b$, but the general $N$ case seems as well difficult to get. 
I thought there might be some symmetric functions and continuity arguments on the functions $y_i = f_i(x_1,\ldots,x_N) that would allow to conclude quickly, but in the end it would just give the same constraints. So let's call it "solved".

Answer (score 0):

If you draw $P(X)$ and $bP(X+a)$ you will see that, if $a$ is quite less than the minimum separation between the zeros and $b$ enough less than $1$ as not to alter the relative position of the min/max, then the sum will have simple zeros which shall between $x_k \pm a$.